# Какие именно нужны карты для работы с d3

Tags: d3.js

Недавно начал изучать D3 js и возник небольшой вопрос, какие именно расширения можно использовать для показа карты с помощью D3, потому что мне нужна карта определённой области РФ(Саратовская область), такую смог найти только на osm в виде xml, может есть какие нибудь другие источники или способы получения данных для создания карты в D3, или же xml тоже подойдёт?